# Mathematica not evaluating q derivative of Jacobi theta function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

Jacobi theta functions, $\theta_a(u,q)$ for $a=1,2,3,4$ are defined in the unit disk $|q|<1$.

For some reason that I would like to understand, Mathematica does not evaluate numerically the $q$ derivatives of these functions, regardless the value of $u$ (at least for the dozen of values that I tried).

Plotting their imaginary and real parts shows that all of them undergo the same problem.

```
Plot[{Re[(EllipticTheta^(0,0,1))[1,-.5,q]],Im[(EllipticTheta^(0,0,1))[1,-.5,q]]},{q,0,1}]
Plot[{Re[(EllipticTheta^(0,0,1))[2,-.5,q]],Im[(EllipticTheta^(0,0,1))[2,-.5,q]]},{q,0,1}]
Plot[{Re[(EllipticTheta^(0,0,1))[3,-.5,q]],Im[(EllipticTheta^(0,0,1))[3-.5,q]]},{q,0,1}]
Plot[{Re[(EllipticTheta^(0,0,1))[4,-.5,q]],Im[(EllipticTheta^(0,0,1))[4,-.5,q]]},{q,0,1}]
```

Heuristically, the limit point is 0.52830188679244577999999999999999...999...

```
D[EllipticTheta[1,-0.28I,q],q]/.q->0.52830188679244577999999999
```

> ```
> 0. +0.909738 I
> ```

Evaluation above it returns no result;

```
D[EllipticTheta[1,-0.28I,q],q]/.q->0.52830188679244578
```

> ```
> (EllipticTheta^(0,0,1))[1,0. -0.28 I,0.528302]
> ```

Comment: Does `Plot[{Re[D[EllipticTheta[1, -.5, x], x] /. x -> q], 
  Im[D[EllipticTheta[1, -.5, x], x] /. x -> q]}, {q, 0, 1}]` give what you expect?

Comment: Thank you for your proposal; unfortunately it does not work and the plot stops above the 0.52 value as well...

Comment: I don't believe *Mathematica* is able to symbolically deal with derivatives with respect to the nome; a numerical approach can be pursued here, however. Care will be needed when the nome is near the unit circle.

Comment: @J.M., So it is structural... I'll get around differently. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, one can use the [PDE satisfied by the Jacobi theta functions](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/EllipticTheta1/13/02/0002/) to compute the required values:

```
With[{z = -7 I/25, q = 0.52830188679244577999999999},
     {Derivative[0, 0, 1][EllipticTheta][1, z, q],
      -Derivative[0, 2, 0][EllipticTheta][1, z, q]/(4 q)}]
   {0.9097375919067572916312 I, 0.*10^-23 + 0.90973758336986133322032 I}
```

(Note that there is a discrepancy between the two evaluations, but I am more inclined to trust the second result instead of the first, since computing the $z$-derivatives for theta functions is much more numerically well-behaved.)

Now, for the case in the OP that could not be numerically evaluated:

```
With[{z = -7 I/25, q = 0.52830188679244578},
     -Derivative[0, 2, 0][EllipticTheta][1, z, q]/(4 q)]
   9.99066*10^-16 + 0.909738 I
```

Comment: Agreed, I had eventually resorted to this as well.